# Laravel 5.2 Log in error

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

Im having a trouble logging in, cant seemt to find the error. heres what ive done so far.

heres my error:

ErrorException in HireDashboardController.php line 20:
Trying to get property of non-object

```
in HireDashboardController.php line 20
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\doneded\app\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Hirer\HireDashboardController.php', '20', array()) in HireDashboardController.php line 20
at HireDashboardController->getIndex()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(HireDashboardController), 'getIndex'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('getIndex', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(HireDashboardController), object(Route), 'getIndex') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HireDashboardController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getIndex') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Hirer\HireDashboardController', 'getIndex') in Route.php line 174
```

heres my controller:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
          $rules = [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
          ];

          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

          if($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Something went wrong, please check your input.');
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
          }

          if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'privilege' => 1])){
              if(Auth::user()->status == 2){
                  return Redirect::to('hirer');
              }
              else{
                  return Redirect::to('specialist');
              }
              return Redirect::to("account");
          }
          else{
              Session::flash('error', 'Something went wrong. Please check your input');
              return back()->withInput();
          }


      }


       public function getSession($id)
        {
              $result = User::where('id',$id)->first();
              if($result){
                    Session::put('session', $result);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }


      public static function user(){
            return Session::get('result');
        }
```

and heres my getIndex.

```
 function getIndex(){

    $data['users'] = User::where('id', MainController::user()->id)->first();
    return view('frontend.dashboard.hirer.hirer_dashboard')->with($data);


  }
```

Comment: In

`public static function user(){
            return Session::get('result');
        }`

You are trying to get from the session 'result' but where exactly its value has been assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're doing a key name mismatch while storing and fetching data from session.

You are storing as `session`:

```
if($result) {
    Session::put('session', $result);
    return true;
}
```

But later, you are trying to access as `result`:

```
return Session::get('result');
```